# How can i get the same "width"?

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a personal website, not a responsive website but i just want to have same "layouting" at least between different screens (not mobile).

For example :

```
<div class="first-div">
   <div class="second-div"></div>
</div>
```

CSS looks like :

```
.first-div{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background-color:blue;
 }

.second-div{
   width:1380px;
   height:1000px;
   background-color:red;
 }
```

When i test this in my 13" screen the red (second div) is quiet, but, in another laptop (even 13") i have to scroll horizontally to see all the second div (the red one).

My question is what is the good width to set even if i do not want a responsive design ?

Comment: what matters is your targeted resolution, not the physical screen size. When you use the same physical screen size with different resolutions, the results are different. What is your targeted resolution?

Comment: Thank you @KhanhTO. But how can i set width (or height) by keeping in mind that those values would be okay in different resolutions ? what is the good value ? % or px ?

Comment: I think you have no choice but to use media query if you want to use fixed width: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries . That means you have to introduce some responsiveness to your site

Comment: It always depends on what your design goal is, usually if you're trying to make full-screen UI you need to use % values

Answer (score 2):

I guess by using the words `same "layouting"` and `same “width”` you mean **percent** sizing.

if you change your css to this for example and give the first div a `position: relative`:

```
.first-div{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background-color:blue;
  position: relative; 
 }

.second-div{
   width:95%;
   height:95%;
   background-color:red;
 }
```

you'll almost get the same layout in every screen, so that for example the first div fills the whole screen and the second one gets only 95%

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
.first-div{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background-color:blue;
 }

.second-div{
  margin:0px auto;
  width:98%;
  height:98%;
  background-color:red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're going on fixed width, some screens will have to scroll.

You're mixing relative and fixed here.

If you want to make sure it doesn't go over a certain limit, use `max-width`, and accept that some screens won't work as expected.